# p-torsion in Picard group of simply-connected variety of char p

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of char $p>0$ and $X$ be a proper smooth variety over $k$ that is simply connected. Then we know $Pic(X)$ does not contain any $\ell$-torsion for $\ell \not= p$, so Picard variety $Pic^0$ is trivial and $Pic(X)$ is a finitely generated abelian group.

Do we have $Pic(X)[p]=0$ as well? What if $X$ is only assumed to be tamely simple connected?

Comment: A smooth projective surface in characteristic 2 that is a specialization from characteristic $0$ of a smooth Enriques surface can have trivial 'etale fundamental group.  These are the "classical" and "supersingular" Enriques surfaces.  In the classical case, $\text{Pic}(X)[2]$ is finite and 'etale of length 2.  In the supersingular case, $\text{Pic}(X)[2]$ is a nonreduced group scheme of length $2$, namely $\alpha_2$.  The book by Cossec and Dolgachev is an excellent reference.  The relation between torsion in Pic and $\pi_1$ is part of "Cartier duality".

Comment: Can this also happen for $p > 2$?

Comment: @TKe "Can this also happen for $p>2$?"  I do not understand the question.

Comment: @JasonStarr: I meant: Are there also simply connected smooth proper varieties $X$ over algebraically closed fields of characteristic $p > 2$ with $\mathrm{Pic}(X)[p] \neq 0$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What follows is more relevant to TKe's question in the comments than it is to the original question.  Regarding the original question, I believe that Enriques surfaces in characteristic 2 provide the simplest and best-studied example of this phenomenon.

However, this phenomenon does happen in every characteristic.  For every prime integer $p\geq 5$, let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$, and let $\mu_{p,k}$ denote the $k$-group scheme $\text{Spec}(A)$ with multiplication map $m$ where $$A:= k[t]/\langle t^p - 1 \rangle, \ \ m^*(t) = t\otimes t\in A\otimes_k A.$$  Denote by $W$ the projective $k$-scheme $\text{Proj}(B)$ with an $\mathcal{O}(1)$-linearized action $s$ of $\mu_{p,k}$ where $$B=k[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{p-1}], \ \ s^*(x_\ell) = t^\ell x_\ell.$$  As a $k$-scheme, $W$ is projective space of dimension $p-1$.  The action $s$ is free on the complement of the $p$ coordinate points.

Denote by $q:W\to V$ the geometric quotient of the action $s$.  This morphism is flat away from the images of the coordinate points.  Denote by $Z\subset V$ the image of the set of the coordinate points, and denote by $U$ the open complement of $Z$ in $V$.  As the target of a flat $k$-morphism from a smooth $k$-scheme, also $U$ is a smooth $k$-scheme.  By SGA 2, for a sufficiently ample, sufficiently general hypersurface $T$ in $V$ that is disjoint from the finite scheme $Z$, the restriction map on fundamental groups, resp. Picard groups, from $V$ to $T$ is an isomorphism, and the same holds for the restriction map from $W$ to $q^{-1}(T)$.

Since $W$ is simply connected, also $q^{-1}(T)$ is simply connected.  Thus, every finite, étale $T$-scheme, say $\nu:T'\to T$, admits a $T$-morphism from $q^{-1}(T)$.  If $T'$ is integral, then the induced field extension $k(T)\to k(T')$ is a subextension of the field extension $k(T)\to k(q^{-1}(T))$.  Since this field extension has degree $p$, it follows that $\nu$ is an isomorphism.  Therefore $T$ is algebraically simply connected.

On the other hand, the standard character of $\mu_{p,k}$, i.e., inclusion of $\mu_{p,k}$ in $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$, induces a $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$-torsor on $T$.  Geometrically, this is the quotient of $q^{-1}(T)\times_{\text{Spec}(k)}\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$ by the diagonal action of $\mu_{p,k}$.  This $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$-torsor is equivalent to an invertible sheaf.  That invertible sheaf is $p$-torsion, since the standard character of $\mu_{p,k}$ is $p$-torsion.